# Import feature es6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to use "import" using es6 feature , but it seems to doesn't work on the browser compiler , there is any way to use the "import" feature ?

Comment: What do you mean by "browser compiler", do you mean the interpreter built into the browser itself (in which case, which browser?), or do you mean a transpiler such as babel?

Comment: I want to use the interpreter built into the browser itself(Chrome).

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

It is what you need to 'convert' es6 feature to es5 compatible code.

Comment: I want to use the interpreter built into the browser itself(Chrome).